# Extracting data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables named, `Student, Applications, Company, Internships`. Their primary keys are `s_id, a_id, c_id, i_id`. Further Internships has a columns named by_c_id and applications has by_s_id, for_i_id.

So how can one show the Applications for the internship having i_id="something".

User logged in with c_id should see

```
Student's Details
Answer in Application.
```

How will this be achieved.

I know I might get down to zero rep due to this question, but its all so confusing.

```
Select Student's Detail from Student where by_s_id=s_id, select Answers from Applications, where for_i_id=i_id.
```

**Edit**

Expected output is similar to online job search platforms where company can see the details of the applicant and his response to their questions.

Here responses are stored in Application, Applicant's details are in Student.

**Another Edit**

This is how I achieved it. I know its not the right way, but I missed join and view classes in my previous semester.

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM APPLICATIONS
        WHERE
        for_i_id='$i_id'";
$query1= mysqli_query($dbhandle, $query);

$count= mysqli_num_rows($query1);
if(!$query1 || $count==0)
{
echo "No Applications to be displayed";
}
else
{
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1))
{
echo $row['by_s_id'];

$query2 ="SELECT `Question1`,`Question2` FROM INTERNSHIPS
          WHERE
          i_id='".$row['for_i_id']."' ";

$query3= mysqli_query($dbhandle, $query2);

$s_id=$row['by_s_id'];

$query4= "SELECT * FROM STUDENT
          WHERE
          id='$s_id'";

$query5= mysqli_query($dbhandle,$query4);
if(!$query3)
{
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
        exit;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some sample date and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using LEFT JOIN to join the Students and Internships tables to the Applications Table:

```
SELECT Student.FirstName, Student.FamilyName, Applications.Answers FROM Applications
LEFT JOIN Student ON Applications.by_s_id=Student.id 
LEFT JOIN Internships ON Applications.for_i_id=Internships.i_id  
WHERE Internships.i_id='something';
```

In this case no foreign keys should be necessary.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction here. Thanks and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming : One application pertains to one internship and one application pertains to one student.

```
Select S.*, A.* From Students S, Applications A, Internships I Where S.s_id = I.s_id And A.i_id = I.i_id And I.i_id = 'something'
```

Needless to say, you have to ensure the presence of `primary keys` and `foreign keys` in the four tables appropriately. The query may have to be different if there are `one-to-many relationships`. I suggest you read up on the keywords I have used in my answer, to understand what's going on.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. And one application is sent by only one student for one particular internship in one company. I was able to design the DB with ease, however this one last thing got me.

Comment: May I request you to mark one of the responses as an accepted answer so that the question is marked as resolved ?